# Regular expression to get an srcattribute from HTML string

Tags: java, html, string

In my String It may contain single/multiple "src"..I want to fetch that src value link..

String is like:

```
"<p>Lets take an example</p> 
<p>
<img alt="\therefore its your address\\"
 src="http://localhost:8080/image?%5Ctherefore%20P%5B1&amp;plus;%5Cfrac%
 %28n-2%29%7D%7B100%7D%5D%3DP%5B1&amp;plus;%5Cfrac%7B4n%7D%7B100%7D%5D%3D930%5C%5C%
 %5C%5C%206n-12%3D4n%5C%5C%202n%3D12%5C%5C%20n%3D6%5C%5C%20%5Ctherefore%20P%5B1&amp;plus
5Cfrac%7B4%5Ctimes6%7D%7B100%7D%5D%3D930%5C%5C%20P%3D%5Cfrac%7B930%5Ctimes100%7D%7B124%7D%5C%5C%20P%3DRs.%5C%20750" /></p> "
```

or may like:

```
 "<p>Lets take an example</p> <p><img alt="\therefore its your  \\" src="http://http://localhost:8080/image?%5Cthe
 refore%20P%281&amp;plus;%5Cfrac%7B20%7D%7B100%7D%29%5En%
 C%20P%281.2%29%5En%3E2P%5C%5C" /></p> <p>its your another address</p> <p>may be your address is<img alt="aoouern " 
 src="http://http://localhost:8080/image?281.2%29%5E2P%3D1.44P" />
 </p> <p>or its
 <img alt="(1.2)^3P=1.728P" src="http://localhost:8080/image?%281.2%29%5E3P%3D1.728P" />
 </p> <p>or you can do <img alt="lets thake this" 
  src="http://localhost:8080/image?%281.2%29%5E4P%3D2.0736P" /></p> <p>so, your are clear?;</p> "
```

What I have done is that:

```
String s = "src=";
int ix = solution_box.indexOf(s)+s.length();
String value = solution_box.substring(ix, solution_box.indexOf("\"", ix+1));
value = value.substring(1);
System.out.println(value);
```

when there is only one "src" in my string then I can fetch that src value..but when String contactins multiple src value then it returing only one src value..

How Can I get multiple also???What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do not use regex. use a HTML parser

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code :

```
             Pattern p=null;
             Matcher m= null;
             String word0= null;
             String word1= null;

             p= Pattern.compile(".*<img[^>]*src=\"([^\"]*)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
             m= p.matcher(solution_box);
             while (m.find())
                  {
                 word0=m.group(1);
                 System.out.println(word0.toString());
                  }
```

regular expression is not a good practice..